# Web API access token not refreshing after it's expired

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, access-token, .net-5, refresh-token

I can refresh the access token when its valid, but after the expiry date I can't refresh it anymore. I have the exact same problem as him [Web API refresh token not refreshing when access token is expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49421002/web-api-refresh-token-not-refreshing-when-access-token-is-expired) but I didn't find any solution.

That's how I generate the access token:

```
public async Task<string> GenerateAccessToken(User _User)
        {
            var userId = _User.Id.ToString();
            var userName = _User.UserName;

            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userId),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName)
            };
            var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(_User);

            foreach (var role in roles) claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));


            var secret = "";

            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret));

            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10),
                SigningCredentials = creds
            };

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

            return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

        }
```

After some debugging I found out this function gives me the error:

```
        public ClaimsPrincipal GetPrincipalFromExpiredToken(string _Token)
        {
            var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("")),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
            IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            SecurityToken securityToken;

            var principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(_Token, tokenValidationParameters, out securityToken);
            var jwtSecurityToken = securityToken as JwtSecurityToken;
            if (jwtSecurityToken == null || !jwtSecurityToken.Header.Alg.Equals("hs256", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                throw new SecurityTokenException("Invalid token");

            return principal;
        }
```

To be more specific this line

```
            var principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(_Token, tokenValidationParameters, out securityToken);
```

I receive the following response when I try to refresh it:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenExpiredException: IDX10223: Lifetime validation failed. The token is expired. ValidTo: '04/25/2022 13:28:11', Current time: '04/25/2022 15:06:26'.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Validators.ValidateLifetime(Nullable`1 notBefore, Nullable`1 expires, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateLifetime(Nullable`1 notBefore, Nullable`1 expires, JwtSecurityToken jwtToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateTokenPayload(JwtSecurityToken jwtToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& validatedToken)
   at rentalAppAPI.BLL.Helper.TokenHelper.GetPrincipalFromExpiredToken(String _Token) in C:\Users\Alex\source\repos\rentalAppAPI\rentalAppAPI.BLL\Helper\ITokenHelper.cs:line 86
   at rentalAppAPI.BLL.Managers.AuthManager.Refresh(RefreshModel refreshModel) in C:\Users\Alex\source\repos\rentalAppAPI\rentalAppAPI.BLL\Managers\AuthManager.cs:line 83
   at rentalAppAPI.Controllers.AuthController.Refresh(RefreshModel model) in C:\Users\Alex\source\repos\rentalAppAPI\rentalAppAPI\Controllers\AuthController.cs:line 45
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I looked up after this error
[SecurityTokenExpiredException Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.securitytokenexpiredexception?view=azure-dotnet)

> Throw this exception when a received Security Token has expiration time in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `ValidateLifetime = true,` to `false`, if it still doesn't work, changing `RequireExpirationTime` to `false` as well.

In your `var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters{}`, you set the validate life time as true, that means when you try to refresh a valid access token, the token can be decoded and will return the principals correctly, but when you try to refresh an expired access token, since the token is expired, it can't be decoded.

When we write the refresh logic, we need to keep the `ValidateAudience, ValidateIssuer, ValidateLifetime, RequireExpirationTime` to false so that we can decode the access token anyway...

Comment: Changing  ValidateLifetime = false worked for me. Thank you!